# Graph search on Google app engine with ndb (python). Efficiency problems

Tags: python, google-app-engine, breadth-first-search

I have been trying to implement a simple graph search on google app engine.  this is my first ever gae project and python project, and graph search! so learning by doing (it wrong, probably).  I have a large cvs file of connections between vertices uploaded as an ndb database

```
class Connection(ndb.Model):
    vertexid = ndb.StringProperty()
    connectedto = ndb.StringProperty()
```

there are about 8000 vertices, each of which is connected to a few others, so there are a total of about 14,000 connections in total, so 14,000 entities in the connection ndb.  already i guess it would be more efficient to store each vertix as a single entity with a repeated connection variable, but i am not sure how to upload my cvs data properly to do that.  also in that case i could use the ids as the keys, and use gets instead of fetches below, which may speed things up?

anyway, I am doing a breadth-first search, based on some python code from this post [How to trace the path in a Breadth-First Search?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8922060/breadth-first-search-trace-path), so i used that and fiddled with it a bit to get it to work:

```
def bfs(origin, destination):   
queue = []
# push the first path into the queue
queue.append(str(origin.vertexid))
count = 0
while queue:
    # get the first path from the queue
    if len(queue) ==1:
        path = queue.pop(0)
        node = path
    else:
        path = queue.pop(0)
        node=path[-1]               
    # get the last node from the path

    # path found
    if node == destination.vertexid:
        return path
    if count>21000:
        return count
    # enumerate all adjacent nodes, construct a new path and push it into the queue
    nodeconns=Connection.query(Connection.vertexid == node).fetch(10)        
    for nodeconn in nodeconns:
        count = count+1
        new_path = []
        new_path.append(path)
        new_path.append(str(nodeconn.connectedto))
        queue.append(new_path)
```

So anyway, it works for origin and destination close to each other (6 or 7 connections apart), but seems to scale very badly for vertices far apart.

is this because it has to read all the data from the datastore?  i dont understand quite why its so slow even with a cap of 21000 tries, like above, it takes 50 seconds or so on my SSD laptop before timing out (count>21,000) on an origin and destination which are quite distant.

combined with all the reads to the ndb database that are going on, this cant be good to run online (i have only been running it locally).

so... i guess my questions are,  is there some fundamental flaw in the algorithm above?  is it a stupid idea to run a graph search based on an ndb in google app engine? is there some more sensible way to represent the graph?  maybe there's some existing packages that can do this for me? (I found some code for dijkstra's algorithm, but not really sure how to interface it with my data)

Thanks!!

Comment: ah i forgot to account for cycles. adding `if nodeconn.connection not in path:` to the final loop helps things allot! still, all the queries to the ndb are quite slow and resource consuming. i guess there's no way to get app engine to keep the whole database in cache?

Comment: Just in case anyone else comes across this question, i basically solved it.  I turned my database into a single entry for each vertex with a repeated item connection entry.  Then I switched over to a Djikstra algorithm, and its works amazingly well.  So either the N^2 scaling in the breadth-first algorithm was just to bad for my graph, or i did something wrong in the above algorithm

Comment: I just came across it, and am facing a similar problem... thanks for the follow up. Is the project you are working on public?

Comment: hi chris, i used this for the Djikstra algorithm, with only very minor modifications, http://code.activestate.com/recipes/119466-dijkstras-algorithm-for-shortest-paths/?in=user-218935    if that doesnt help i can make my version public, but needs a bit of tidying first :)

Comment: I'll dig around there first... i'm doing this as a side project and don't want to request any more help unless I know I need it. This link looks like it will be helpful.