# Shortest path between connected pairs of tuples

Tags: python-3.x, path, tuples, shortest

I'm new at this and i would be really greatfull for any kind of help...I have a list of tuples and I have to find shortest path between connected pairs of tuples.
For example, I have list called pairs = [(1,2),(2,4),(1,3),(3,1),(4,3)] and i have to find shortest path for:

```
1 to 2, 1 to 3 and 1 to 4
2 to 1, 2 to 3 and 2 to 4
3 to 1, 3 to 2 and 3 to 4
```

In this list pairs, if I search for connection between 1 to 3, I have to possible outcomes:

```
1) (1,3) 
2) (1,2)-(2,4)-(4,3)
```

and of course the shortest one is the first one - (1,3)

Thanx...

Comment: are the path weighted?? mean from 1 to 2 is it the same distance as from 1 to 3 ??? @user2923389

Comment: no there are no weights...
In this list pairs, if I search for connection between 1 to 3, I have to possible outcomes:

1) (1,3) 
2) (1,2)-(2,4)-(4,3)
and of course the shortest one is the first one - (1,3) and output of my program has to be 1.

For instance if the shortest path for 1 to 3 was (1,2)-(2,4)-(4,3), then output of my program has to be 3 because there are three pairs

Comment: Can you add language tag? Or it it's too general, maybe `algorithm` tag or something. At first it looks like Python, however, we can't read your mind and adding the tag can help you get the best answer.

Comment: of course, sorry....the programming language is Python

Answer (score 1):

If you only search for the shortest path between two numbers (lets call them nodes) and the length of the edges between them is 1, you can use [BFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search), if they have some other distance, you can use [Dijkstra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm). Since both are graph algorithms, you may need to change them a little since you have only a list of edges, not graph structure.

Answer (score 0):

Use [BFS](http://www.eecs.yorku.ca/course_archive/2006-07/W/2011/Notes/BFS_part2.pdf) for solving a shortest path problem in an unweighted graph like that.

Pseudo code :

```
Create Queue q;
push into q starting node and mark distance to starting node as 0.
while(q is not empty){
 get n : first elemnt in the queue
 get all connected nodes to n that are not yet visited and push them to the queue:
 mark the distance to those node as the distance to n + 1.
}
```

Example : assuming your start node is 1.

connections you have in the graph :

```
   1->2,  1->3,  1->4
   2->1,  2->3,  2->4
   3->1,  3->2,  3->4
```

Set a visited array of boolean : visited [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8922060/breadth-first-search-trace-path) = {false,false,false,false}, and a distance array dist[4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8922060/breadth-first-search-trace-path) = {inf,inf,inf,inf} and parent array = {-1,-1,-1,-1}.

now push Node 1 into the queue Q, set it distance to 0 and parent to 1 then start:

Iteration 1 state:

```
Queue = {1}
Dist = {0,inf,inf,inf}
visited= {true,false,false,false}
parent= {1,-1,-1,-1}
```

Iteration 2 :

the only node in the Queue is 1, you pick it  and push their neighbors to Queue which are nodes: 2,3,4. update their distances

```
Queue = {2,3,4}
Dist = {0,1,1,1}
visited= {true,false,false,false}
parent= {1,1,1,1}
```

and so on until you get an empty queue. (means you have visited all the nodes).

in this example you'll see that the distance to node 3 is Dist[3](http://eddmann.com/posts/depth-first-search-and-breadth-first-search-in-python/) = 1, the parent of this node is parent[3](http://eddmann.com/posts/depth-first-search-and-breadth-first-search-in-python/) = 1 (in case you want to reconstruct the path).

for more information check [BFS](http://www.eecs.yorku.ca/course_archive/2006-07/W/2011/Notes/BFS_part2.pdf) and also an implementation in Python : [Python BFS DFS](http://eddmann.com/posts/depth-first-search-and-breadth-first-search-in-python/) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8922060/breadth-first-search-trace-path)

Comment: thanx,but as i said that i am new in this i would rather not use algorithms like this...instead i wrote code that returns all connected nodes...do you think if it is possible using this to find the shortest path

Comment: Hmmm, altough i think that BFS is pretty easy implementation, if you dont want to use it, you can write a recursive solution and brute force all the paths *Which if your the number of nodes you have is > 20* would not work :/ @user2923389

Answer (score 0):

```
def components_pairs(pairs):

    components = []

    for v1, v2 in pairs:
        for component in components:
             if v1 in component or v2 in component:
                 component.add(v1)
                 component.add(v2)
                 break
        else:
             components.append({v1, v2})

    return components

pairs = [(1,2),(1,3),(2,4),(3,1),(4,3)]

print(components_pairs(pairs))
```

Answer (score -3):

This is [Travelling salesman problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem). You can use genetic algorithm, it will goal a goal with the lowest cost of operations. Greetings.

Comment: As is stated in the link you provided, traveling salesman problem is something *completely* different. Also, it's NP-hard, which basically means you have no general effective algorithm to solve the problem.