# Filling in a concave polygon represented as a binary matrix

Tags: python, numpy, concave, concave-hull

In my task, I represent a concave polygon as a matrix of ones and zeros, where one means that the given point belongs to the polygon. For instance, the following are a simple square and a u-shaped polygon:

```
0 0 0 0     0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 1 0     0 1 1 0 0 1 1
0 1 1 0     0 1 1 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0     0 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

However, sometimes I get an incomplete representation, in which: (1) all boundary points are included, and (2) some internal points are missing. For example, in the following enlarged version of the u-shaped polygon, the elements at positions (1,1), (1,6), (3,1), ..., (3,6)* are "unfilled". The goal is to fill them (i.e., change their value to `1`).

```
1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1
1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Do you know if there's an easy way to do this in Python/NumPy?

*(row, column), starting counting from the top left corner

Comment: how do you decide that these are not positions (3, 0), (4, 0) are not the ones that are supposed to be filled? is it related to path of zeros touching the "border" of the whole matrix?

Comment: You mean the middle two zeros in the very first row?

Comment: Oh yes, sorry I mismatched rows and columns.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand it correctly, but those two zeros are outside the border of the u-shaped polygon defined by the outermost layer of ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very well known problem in image processing that can be solved using [morphological operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_morphology).

With that, you can use scipy's [`binary_fill_holes`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.morphology.binary_fill_holes.html) to fill the holes in your mask:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from scipy.ndimage import binary_fill_holes
>>> data = np.array([[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
                     [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
                     [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
                     [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
                     [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])

>>> filled = binary_fill_holes(data).astype(int)
>>> filled
array([[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe there would exist some generic purpose solution in Python or whatever. This is classic breadth-first graph search. For each 0 either exists a path of adjacent zeros, so that at least one of those zeros is at position (y,x) so that (x = 0 or y = 0 or x = maxx or y = maxy) or this 0 should be changed to 1.

Maybe an answer here will be helpful to you: [How to trace the path in a Breadth-First Search?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8922060/breadth-first-search-trace-path)

Comment: Thanks! Actually this was my first solution, but I was looking for something like the `binary_fill_holes` function in the other answer.

Comment: Because your first statement contradicts the accepted answer. It does exists a generic solution. Binary hole-filling is a basic operation in image processing. While the answer is not bad (gives some hints of how to do stuff) it has an obvious wrong sentence that a bit of image processing knowledge would have solved. Ultimately the OP asks "is there an easy way on  python/numpy" and your answer is "no" which is wrong.

Comment: OK, I get it. However I fill the urge to emphasize that the answer doesn't state a *hard no*. I just said I do not believe there exists (but feel free to carry on searching). While I surely know close to nothing about image processing I saw a possible solution in graph algorithms. I wouldn't personally downvote similiar answer for the sake of overconfident author :) but you are of course free to do so. Thank you for explanation.